# How to append a new line to a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to append a new line in a list in python to write to my text file any suggestions?

```
header = ['Employee ID','Type','Routing Number','Account Number']
header.append("\n")

strOtherLine = [strSsn,strThisType,strThisRoute,strThisAcct]       
header.append("\n" + strOtherLine)

fc_otherfile  = r"c:\******\*****\gah\\" + strOtherSavedFile
#===Writing to the text file
with open(fc_otherfile,'w', newline='') as t:
    dirdep = csv.writer(t, delimiter="\t")
    dirdep.writerow(header)
```

This is what I get in my text file:

```
 Employee ID    Type    Routing Number  Account Number  ""  ['###########', 'Checking', '###########','###########']    ['###########', 'Checking', '###########', '###########']
```

But what I want is this:

```
 Employee ID    Type    Routing Number  Account Number  
 ###########  Checking  ###########  ###########
 ###########  Checking  ###########  ###########
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using lists when you should be using strings:

```
header = 'Employee ID\tType\tRouting Number\tAccount Number'
header += "\n"

strOtherLine = strSsn +'\t'+ strThisType +'\t'+ strThisRoute +'\t'+ strThisAcct       
header += "\n"+ strOtherLine

fc_otherfile  = r"c:\******\*****\gah\\" + strOtherSavedFile
#===Writing to the text file
with open(fc_otherfile,'w', newline='') as t:
    t.write(header)

#confirm write was successful
with open(fc_otherfile,'r') as t2:
     print(t2.read())
```

Comment: My text file looks like this now         --E m p l o y e e  the tab leaves spaces between characters

Comment: It's still all on one line in my text file

Comment: Puzzling. I added more code to answer. Please retry.

Comment: I mean it works how I want it to in the python print function but when i open my text file it's still all on the same line I don't think the the new line break is working

Comment: okay - so this some other code (or editor) that's not loading correctly ?

Comment: it's just a regular text file

Comment: I figured it out I had to use "\r\n"

Comment: Python should convert the \n to the requirements of the OS. Did you write on one system then read on another?

Comment: No not that I know of

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a string of a list using `' '.join()`. Whenever appending line use obj.write('\n') after that.

```
Example: Using text file.

MyData = ['I', 'am', 'fine']
line1 = '    '.join(MyData)

with open('file.txt', 'a+') as data:
    data.write(line1)
    data.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you love loops you could try something like this:

```
toinsert = ""
for each in header:
    toinsert.append(str(each)+"\t")
toinsert.rstrip()  #remove trailing "\t"
toinsert += "\n"

for each in strOtherLine:
    toinsert.append(str(each)+"\t")
toinsert.rstrip()
toinsert += "\n"

with open('file.txt', 'a+') as data:
    data.write(toinsert)
```